# Is $f(x,y)=(x+1)(y+1)$ strictly convex over $[0,\infty)^2$?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

I'd like to know whether $f(x,y)=(x+1)(y+1)$ is strictly convex over $\mathbb{R^2_+}$.

I try to work with the Hessian, I have:
$Hf(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}0&1 \\ 1&0\end{bmatrix}$

This gives me the eigenvalues $\lambda=-1$ and $\lambda=1$. Since they are not both greater than $0$, I would think it's not strictly convex. But is it the right conclusion considering that the function is only defined on $\mathbb{R^2_+}$? How could I take the domain into account?

Answer (score 1):

It's not even convex. $f(1,9) = f(9,1) = 20$ but $f(5,5) = 36 > 20$.

If there is anywhere that the Hessian is not positive semidefinite, that means it can't be convex or strictly convex, as there are points near there  violate the convexity condition.

Comment: I think I confused with concavity. Does what you say hold for concavity?

Comment: Yes, a Hessian needs to be negative semidefinite everywhere else the function can't be concave. Your functions is not concave either because $f(1,1) = 4$, $f(2,2) = 9$ and $f(3,3) = 16$ and $\frac{4+16}{2} = 10 > 9$.